# Send numbers to other cells in excel

Tags: excel, vba

well, i write a code for get All Possible Combinations Of a number in 4 digit
and worked well, but i want send each number to opposite Cells

```
Dim N As Long, ary(1 To 4) As Long
N = Application.InputBox(prompt:="enter value", Type:=1)
xxx = 1

For i = 0 To N
    For J = 0 To N
        For k = 0 To N
            For l = 0 To N
                If i + J + k + l = N Then
                    ary(1) = i
                    ary(2) = J
                    ary(3) = k
                    ary(4) = l
                    Call LittleSort(ary())
                    Cells(xxx, 1).Value = "'" & ary(1) & ary(2) & ary(3) & ary(4)
                    xxx = xxx + 1
                End If
            Next l
        Next k
    Next J
Next i

Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
End Sub

Public Sub LittleSort(ByRef InOut)

Dim i As Long, J As Long, Low As Long
Dim Hi As Long, Temp As Variant

Low = LBound(InOut)
Hi = UBound(InOut)

J = (Hi - Low + 1) \ 2
Do While J > 0
    For i = Low To Hi - J
      If InOut(i) > InOut(i + J) Then
        Temp = InOut(i)
        InOut(i) = InOut(i + J)
        InOut(i + J) = Temp
      End If
    Next i
    For i = Hi - J To Low Step -1
      If InOut(i) > InOut(i + J) Then
        Temp = InOut(i)
        InOut(i) = InOut(i + J)
        InOut(i + J) = Temp
      End If
    Next i
    J = J \ 2
Loop
End Sub
```

and worked well, but i want send each number to opposite Cells 
like this
[image]

write this code for do that

```
Sub Text_To_Cols()
Dim ary()
Dim Num As Long, i As Long

Num = Len(Range("A1").Value) - 1
ReDim ary(0 To Num)
For i = 0 To Num
    ary(i) = Array(i, 1)
Next i

Range("A1").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B1"), _
    DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=ary

End Sub
```

My problem is that my 4 numbers are divided into 5 numbers

[image]

how can i do that?

Comment: Change this line in the existing code `Cells(xxx, 1).Value = "'" & ary(1) & ary(2) & ary(3) & ary(4)` to four separate lines that puts each number in a separate cell instead of concatenating into one.  For example `Cells(xxx,2) = ary(1)` and `Cells(xxx,3) = ary(2)` and so forth for the other two.